# How do i write a recursive method to display x^0 + x^1 + x^2 + ... x^n and then display the computed values of x^n?

Tags: java, recursion

I want to write a recursive method to compute

> x^0 + x^1 + x^2 + ... x^n

and then i want to display the values for the computed x^n
ex:

> n = 3 and x =3  the output should be : 1 + 3 + 9 + 27

I have code to compute a recursive method like this but how do i use that method to print each iteration?

My code is :

```
public static double compute(int n, int x){
   
    if(n == 0){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        
        return Math.pow(x , n) + compute(x , n-1);
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Should be `compute(n - 1, x)` instead of `compute(x, n - 1)`.

Comment: You are right. did not catch that. It was seeming to work with those numbers but I guess they were interchangeable. Thanks for catching that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as an alternative.  The key is to save the return from `Math.pow` on the call stack before you print it.  That way the terms will be in the correct order when the method unwinds.

```
double v = compute(3,3);
System.out.println("\nv = " + v);
    
    
public static double compute(int n, int x) {
    double v;
    if (n == 0) {
       System.out.print(1.);
       return 1;
   }
   // save a copy of the power method for printout
   double r = compute(n-1,x)+ (v = Math.pow(x,n));
   System.out.print(" + " + v);
   return r;
}
```

Prints

```
1.0 + 3.0 + 9.0 + 27.0
v = 40.0
```

If you don't want floating point values in your power series display, then just cast `v` to an `int`

Comment: Thanks, It was a simple question but i couldn't wrap my head around it for some reason. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to call `System.out.print()` on each recursive call:

```java
public static double compute(int n, int x) {
  if (n == 0) {
    System.out.print("1");  // print 1 (no "+" here because it's the last call)
    return 1;
  } else {
    double currVal = Math.pow(x, n);   // value for the current x and n
    System.out.print(String.valueOf(currVal) + " + ");  // print currVal with "+"
    return currVal + compute(n - 1, x);  // make recursive call
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I mean, you print the number when you reach there:

```
public static double compute(int n, int x){
   
    if(n == 0){
        System.out.print(1);//It's 1...
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        int number = (int)Math.pow(x , n);
        System.out.print(number + "+");//since n is not 0, there must be data printed after this 
        return number + compute(n - 1 , x);
    }
    
}
```

Or if you want to print from smallest to the largest:

```
    public static double compute(int n, int x){    
        if(n == 0){
            System.out.print(1);//It's 1...
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            int number = (int)Math.pow(x , n);
            try {//needed for the finally statement
                return number + compute(n - 1 , x);
            }finally {//finaly block will be executed even after return
                System.out.print("+" + number);//since n is not 0, there must be data printed before this
            } 
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

public class Demo {

```
public static StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

public static double compute(int n, int x) {

    if (n == 0) {
        stringBuilder.insert(0, x + "^" + n);
        return 1;
    } else {
        stringBuilder.insert(0, " + " + x + "^" + n);
        return Math.pow(x, n) + compute(n - 1, x);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(stringBuilder.append(" = ").append(compute(5, 2)));

}
```

}