# How do i write a recursive method to sum x^n + x^(n-1) + x^(n-2)?

Tags: java, recursion

I posted a question yesterday about how to find the sum of a recursive method

The post is located here: [Recursive method to sum x^0 + x^1 + x^2 + ... +x^n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64885550/how-do-i-write-a-recursive-method-to-display-x0-x1-x2-xn-and-then)

How do i make a recursive method in reverse.

> Ex: x^n + x^(n-1) + x^(n-2) + ... + 3 + 2, + 1

I am having a lot of trouble wrapping my brain around recursive methods and a lot of other resources aren't helping me out. Any help is appreciated. Thanks Everyone!

Comment: what did you come up with?

Comment: `... + 3 + 2 + 1` at the end makes no sense for `x^n + x^n-1 + x^n-2 + ...`

Comment: @KarolDowbecki That is how the question was stated for me when looking at the problem. Figured I would just put the whole thing in. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: It probably meant `... + x^2 + x^1 + x^0`

Comment: Probably, the wording for a lot of the problems I find are always more confusing than they need to be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64886290/5221149) has:

```java
double r = compute(n-1,x)+ (v = Math.pow(x,n));
System.out.print(" + " + v);
```

If we unwrap that nested assignment, it is:

```java
v = Math.pow(x, n);
double r = compute(n - 1, x) + v;
System.out.print(" + " + v);
```

To reverse the output order, just **swap** the `compute()` and `print()` calls. We also need to swap the `" + "` and `v` in the `print` statement.

```java
v = Math.pow(x, n);
System.out.print(v + " + ");
double r = compute(n - 1, x) + v;
```

*That's it!*

```
27.0 + 9.0 + 3.0 + 1.0
v = 40.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much! These stupid recursion questions for some reason are so difficult for me to understand